# How can I make an 'OR' statement in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create an 'OR' sql statement in ActiveRecord 3, I tried all kinds of variations but can't figure it out...

For example I want this query to include multiple 'channel_ids' and have it return all posts for any of the channel IDs. This works for one:

```
Post.where(:user => 'mike').where(:channel_id => 0).limit(20)
```

but I cant figure out how to do it with multiples, I've tried for example:

```
Post.where(:user => 'mike').where(:channel_id => ?, [0,1,2,3]).limit(20)
```

but it didn't work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Arel](http://github.com/rails/arel) methods to do this:

```
t = Post.arel_table
ids = [1,2,3]

Post.where(
  t[:user].eq("mike").or(t[:channel_id].in(ids))
)
```

Comment: works perfect, many thanks. Heard of Arel before and will read up on it now. So neat.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Post.where("posts.user = ? OR posts.channel_id IN (?)", "mike", ids)
```

Comment: You should let ActiveRecord escape lists for you instead of doing it yourself. You can leave `ids` in there as-is, no `join` required and it will be expanded to a comma-separated list for you automatically.