# How do you do a logcal or using two ActiveRelation results returning another relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Given I have the following code

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.from_country(country)
   where(:origin_country_id => country.id)
 end

 def self.for_country(country)
   where(:destination_country_id => :country.id)
 end
end
```

If I want products made and distributed to Germany I can do the following

```
Product.for_country.from_country #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
products = Product.for_country.from_country #=> Array[<Product...>...]
```

In the above case I can chain more relational methods before assigning it to products if I wanted to.

If I want to access all products that involve Germany I can do the following

```
Product.for_country | Product.from_country #=> Array[<Product...>...]
products = Product.for_country | Product.from_country #=> Array[<Product...>...]
```

Here I cannot chain more relational methods before assigning it to products since the result of the OR is an `Array` not an `ActiveRecord`::Relation.

My questions is how can I OR for_country with from_country and get a `ActiveRecord::Relation` as a result?

Ideally something like the following `Product.for_country(country).or(Product.from_country(country))`

Answer (score 0):

[How can I make an 'OR' statement in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587592/activerecord-3-how-can-i-make-an-or-statement)

I know that isn't the exact answer to your question, but I'd say another method such as `involving_country` which used this 'or' logic would make your other code much more readable than chaining `from_country` and `for_country`. Those methods, chained, don't really explain themselves very well.

Comment: The code is only an example of what I am actually trying to do and is not real code. You are right of course for the example give.