# Rails 3: Is there a `AR#or_where`?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause, arel

Is there a `AR#or_where` in Rails 3 as in

```
User.where(cond1).or_where(cond2)
```

?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a method like that in Rails.

I think that the easiest way to do an OR in a WHERE clause is to do something like this:

```
User.where("first_name = ? OR last_name = ?", params[:first_name], "Wilson")
```

If you want to learn the Arel methods (which does have an "or" method), look here: https://github.com/rails/arel#readme. Using Arel and ActiveRecord, you can do the same thing like this:

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:first_name].eq(params[:first_name]).or(User.arel_table[:last_name].eq('Wilson')))
```

Comment: Note to visitors: you can do this method/soln using the same column name for multiple queries, for ex "Model.where('name = ? OR name = ? OR name = ?', 'South Carolina', 'South_Carolina', 'south carolina'") etc...of course you could handle that problem by other methods but this one would work too

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where). This gem allows more powerful ActiveRecord query expressions in Ruby code, without requiring dropping to SQL fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Simply by using `User.where(cond1) | User.where(cond2)`, the || is reserved by ruby!

Comment: It's true that this gets the same result, but it's actually doing two SQL queries and uses the Ruby Array set union operator ([Array#|](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000275)) to concatenate the results into one array. You can see the SQL queries by running the rails console and telling it to log to STDOUT like this: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`, then type `User.where(cond1) | User.where(cond2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain them like that, you've got to dig into arel a bit. See [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587592/activerecord-3-how-can-i-make-an-or-statement).